# Pyramid printing without spaces in python 3

Tags: python

I am new to python and for loops and also new to stack overflow. I am trying to make a pyramid shape with stars using a for loop but without spaces. Any help would truly be appreciated. I cant seem to get it done without spaces

```py
num = int(input("Enter a number of rows: "))
for i in range(0,num):
    for j in range(0,num-i-1):
        print(end=" ")
    for j in range(0,1+i):
        print("*", end=" ")
    print()
```

Comment: what do u mean without any spaces? where do u wanted to ignore spaces?

Comment: do you men you're trying to do it in one line of code? what reason would you have to do that as a beginner? some people do that stuff in code golf but not as you're learning

Comment: remove white space between end=""  double quotes

Comment: change `end = ' '` to `end = ''`, the end argument specifies with what string your printed value ends currently that string is a space so it prints that, to remove the space simply change the end argument to an empty string.

Comment: @MatrixProgrammer So... when you tried that, it still looked like a pyramid to you?

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode yes it did, changing the end argument for the line that prints star does it. The other line at the top that only prints spaces can still have `end = ' '`.

Comment: @MatrixProgrammer We have a different understanding of pyramids then. Your suggestion makes the right side a vertical bar, that doesn't look like a pyramid to me and I'm rather certain it's not what the OP wants, either.

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode Perhaps you did not get what I suggested.

Comment: @MatrixProgrammer Maybe. [What did I do wrong?](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/P680V8FWwdCAKy2/SCFTITNPoSgxLz1Vw0AHKKNpxaUABCCpLDQp3UxdQ6g0CBQUZeaVaKTmpdgqKShpYtdlqJ2JoUNJS0lHAawNqgsirPn/PwA). Edit: Ah... reading your initial comment again, I guess you only meant it as part of the fix?

Answer (score 1):

this is how you can do that in more than one line of code, but still pretty concise, unless someone has a better way!

```py
x=8
for i in range(1,x):
    print((' '*(x-i))+('*'*i)+('*'*(i-1)))
```

But if you really want to do it in one line you can do it like so:

```py
exec("x=int(input('Input max number: '))\nfor i in range(1,x):print((' '*(x-i))+('*'*i)+('*'*(i-1)))")
```

[and as you can see it works!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tzdZv.png)

Answer (score 0):

A very basic approach would be to compute the appropriate number of spaces (indent) and stars to print so you would only need one loop: *Python lets you multiply strings by integers to repeat the string a given number of times*

```
n = 7
for i in range(n):
    print( " "*(n-i-1) + "*"*(2*i+1) )

      *
     ***
    *****
   *******
  *********
 ***********
*************
```

**Using substrings**

You can also approach this by printing a subset of a string containing the maximum possible spaces and stars:

```
n=7
line = " "*n + "**"*n                         # max spaces + max stars
for i in range(n): print(line[i+1:][:n+i])    # relevant part of line

      *
     ***
    *****
   *******
  *********
 ***********
*************
```

this corresponds to extracting the following substrings:

```
               i  line:      "       **************"
      *        0  [1:][:7]    [      *]
     ***       1  [2:][:8]     [     ***]
    *****      2  [3:][:9]      [    *****]
   *******     3  [4:][:10]      [   *******]
  *********    4  [5:][:11]       [  *********]
 ***********   5  [6:][:12]        [ ***********]
*************  6  [7:][:13]         [*************]
```

**Using format strings**

Another way is to use a format string to progressively offset the characters on each line and join the lines with an end of line character:

```
n=7
print("\n".join(f"{'*'*(2*i+1):>{n+i}}" for i in range(n)))

      *
     ***
    *****
   *******
  *********
 ***********
*************
```

or you can leave handling of end of lines to the print function:

```
n=7
pyramid = [f"{'*'*(2*i+1):>{n+i}}" for i in range(n)] # list of lines
print(*pyramid,sep="\n")                              # print all lines
```

or print in a loop:

```
n=7
for i in range(n): print(f"{'*'*(2*i+1):>{n+i}}")
```

The format string right justifies the stars on the line based on the increasing total size (ignoring trailing spaces):

```
                 leading  stars    total
                 spaces   count    length
                          (2i+1)   (n+i)
      *            6       1       7  = n+0
     ***           5       3       8  = n+1
    *****          4       5       9  = n+2
   *******         3       7       10 = n+3
  *********        2       9       11 = n+4
 ***********       1       11      12 = n+5
*************      0       13      13 = n+6
```